# Import Android Activity Templates Intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-activity

The built-in android activity templates are easy to import using Eclipse. However, I am not able to figure out how to use them with Intellij IDEA.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of the Activity templates shown [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html#activity-templates)

- Right click on the project's "Java" or "res" folder
- New
- Activity